# SourceMonitor xml dump to database

Tags: code-analysis, code-metrics, source-monitor

Is there a library or a tool that could parse the xml dump of SourceMonitor and save it in database?

SourceMonitor is a great tool, but I'd like to have better visualization and statistics-over-time of our code, which you really can't get with SourceMonitor.

Answer (score 1):

A useful script is Eden Ridgway's [SourceMonitor Summary Xml File Generation.](http://www.ridgway.co.za/archive/2006/11/28/usefulsourcemonitorreportsincruisecontrol.aspx)